# How to find the length of a wire making a spherical spiral?

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

Suppose you have a Christmas ball, which has a decorative lining around it so that it forms a spherical spiral around it. I want to find how long that decorative lining can be given some parameters. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdXCq.png) is more or less the shape I am looking at. This was taken from Wikipedia at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral#:%7E:text=Spherical%20spirals,-If%20one%20represents&text=A%20rhumb%20line%20(also%20known,with%20respect%20to%20the%20meridians).).

The parametric equations of this were also provided:

$$x = r \cdot \sin(\theta) \cdot \cos(c\theta)$$
$$y = r \cdot \sin(\theta) \cdot \sin(c\theta)$$
$$z = r \cdot \cos(\theta)$$
Where $0 \le \theta \le \pi$.

$c$ is twice the number of turns, and in my specific case, I set $c=8$, just like in the picture, for simplicity sakes. $r$ is the radius, and in my specific case the radius is $r=4cm$.
What I am looking for is the length of the red line. How do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use the parameter $t$ because I'm more comfortable with it. Our parametric equations are:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x( t)\\
y( t)\\
z( t)
\end{bmatrix} =r\begin{bmatrix}
\sin( t)\cos( ct)\\
\sin( t)\sin( ct)\\
\cos( t)
\end{bmatrix}$$
The formula for the arc length is
$$s(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt{\dot{x}(t')^2+\dot{y}(t')^2+\dot{z}(t')^2}~\mathrm{d}t'$$
We can compute
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}( t)\\
\dot{y}( t)\\
\dot{z}( t)
\end{bmatrix} =r\begin{bmatrix}
\cos( t)\cos( ct) -c\sin( ct)\sin( t)\\
\cos( t)\sin( ct) +c\cos( ct)\sin( t)\\
-\sin( t)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now I hope you can trust me when I say that $\dot{x}(t)^2+\dot{y}(t)^2+\dot{z}(t)^2=r^2(c^2\sin^2(t)+1).$ (You can verify the algebra yourself if you want.) Therefore, taking the endpoint of integration to be $\pi$, our integral is
$$s(\pi)=\int_0^\pi r\sqrt{c^2\sin^2(t)+1}~\mathrm{d}t$$
Unfortunately this integral doesn't have any nice expressions in terms of elementary functions, but we can write it as
$$s(\pi)=r\left(E(-c^2)+\sqrt{c^2+1}E\left(\frac{c^2}{c^2+1}\right)\right)$$
Where $E$ denotes the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html). You can evaluate this numerically for different values of $c$ and $r$ if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @K.defaoite's answer
$$s=r\Big[E(-c^2)+\sqrt{c^2+1}E\left(\frac{c^2}{c^2+1}\right)\Big]$$ you could get a quite accurate approximation of the quantity in brackets.

It would write
$$2 c+\frac{2\log (4c)+1}{2c}-\frac{4 \log (4c)-3}{32
   c^3}+\frac{3\log (4c)-3}{64   c^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{c^ 7}\right)$$ and it is quite good as soon as $c>1$.

Just a few numbers for checking
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
c & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 3.82487 & 3.82020 \\
 2 & 5.27053 & 5.27037 \\
 3 & 6.98722 & 6.98721 \\
 4 & 8.81428 & 8.81428 \\
 5 & 10.6969 & 10.6969 \\
 6 & 12.6116 & 12.6116 \\
 7 & 14.5465 & 14.5465 \\
 8 & 16.4951 & 16.4951 \\
 9 & 18.4532 & 18.4532 \\
 10 & 20.4185 & 20.4185
\end{array}
\right)$$

Applied to your case $(r=4,c=8)$ the exact solution is
$$L=8 E(-64)\approx 65.98022986\text{ cm}$$ while the given formula leads to
$$L \sim \frac{5 (6737177+261635 \log (2))}{524288}\approx  65.98022997\text{ cm}$$

Comment: Cool approximation. Is this just Taylor series or perhaps something more advanced?

Comment: @K.defaoite. Say *a kind of ..;*. In fact it is asymptotic analysis. Funny, isn't it ?

Comment: @K.defaoite. I wrote it nicer